# Firebase query optimizable

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `Firebase Database` which looks like :

I have a node named `Products`

```
 Products
    |
    |--------prod1_id
    |         | 
    |         |--name : "prod1"
    |          --state: "free"
    |         
    |
    |---------prod2_id
              | 
              |--name : "prod2"
               --price: "not_free"
```

Then I have the node for users

```
Users
     |
     |--------user1_id
     |         | 
     |         |--name : "user1"
     |          --e-mail: "user1@email.com"
     |          
     |
     |---------user2_id
               | 
               |--name : "user2"
                --e-mail: "user2@email.com"
```

And on my application user can purchase, and only when he/she does, I create a new node called `PurchasedItems` where I store the `User` and `Product`

```
Purchased items
             |
             |--------user1_id
             |         | 
             |         |--prod1: "any_value"
             |          --prod2:  "any_value"
             |         
             |
             |---------user2_id
                       | 
                       |--prod1: "any_value"
```

The thing is that on my query for objects, I do this :

```
 products_ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
```

### WHAT IS THE PROBLEM?

User that is logged in to the app, even if he has bought a product it will show the productNotFree layout because on products I have not any reference to what user has bought this item, but I have something similar on my "TryToPurchase" method because I have a query to the `PurchasedProducts` to see if user has this product or not to make the purchase or not.

On my `onClick()` method I have this to check if user has paid for it or not

```
root_ref.child("PurchasedProducts").child(currentuser).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(model.getProduct_id())){
            showToast("He has that product");
        }
        else{
            showToast("Purchasing");
            //Purchase for it

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

So far I had this `switch()` statement to `setImageResource` but from the query to `products`

**NOTE:layoutFree is for example a box that has not a lock on it, and layoutNotFree is the same box but with a lock**

```
switch (model.getState()) {
        case "free":
            holder.card_image.setImageResource(layoutFree);
            break;
        case "not_free":
            holder.card_image.setImageResource(layoutNotFree));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Now I've faced that if user purchase an item, he/she won't be able to see the layoutFree even if he purchased it, he will see the layout with a lock even if he/she has paid for it.

### What I've thought to do?

On same `onBindViewHolder` where I have the `switch()` statement I could make another query to `Firebase` asking if `currentUser` has this product and if he has that product I put the freeLayout otherwise the NotFreeLayout.

But I think it's kinda dirty, so I put it here to see if there's another way to make it efficient.

### What I'd like to see?

Well, if I'm logged as a user that has paid for one product that has the state "not_free" I'd like to see the product with layout without lock item and also if I pay for an item I create a table `purchasedItems` and I do something like this :

```
root_ref.child("PurchasedProducts").child(currentuser).child(productId).setValue("paid");
```

And also I'd like to see the `RecyclerView` changes the layoutNotFree to layoutFree, is any way to do it instead of making a refresh of the `Activity`? Refresh of `Activity` means that I have to re-do the adapter, create the `RecyclerView` etc...

I hope I've explained it correctly and step by step to avoid confusion, if I did something wrong on question feel free to edit it or question it to me and I'll edit.

Comment: Have  you checked the value of the state?

Comment: @Zoe What state?

Comment: `model.getState()` - Have you checked the value of it in the switch statement to check the value of it at the time?

Comment: @Zoe I've edited the questions I guess I misstyped something and I think now it's clear.

Comment: Retrieve all the childs as json before you add your recyclerView and get the data before you add the view, this way you make one request to Friebase

Comment: @Mohamed Embaby could you make an easy example I don't get you.

Comment: you said  ""I could make another query to Firebase asking if currentUser has this product and if he has that product"". why would you get every-single user and his product alone, in other words you're getting a tree but you're getting it a leaf(node) by leaf(node), every time you get a leaf you consume request if you had large number of users it will make load to Firebase + Firebase has limit requests then you have to buy more. though you can get all the tree once and save it offline and later see what leaf(node) you want. **You do this only in the first time insertion ** because data changes.

Comment: Wow. I did not know that I have a query limit request .... where do I see how much queries I have to do? Could you put an example to how to do it please? I did not know that I have a limit... and I want it to be efficient, please guide me... do I have to have a development database to test and a production database?? I can copy the database and send it to another one to redo the queries limit?

Comment: u forget to mention xD, for Firebase limits and pricing check
https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example, **all products table children** is saved in **one** `ArrayList` with **only one request** to `Firebase Database`.

According to your database schema.

**First,** Define a `Arraylist` of `Products.class` to hold all products details

```
 ArrayList<Products> productsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Second,** define the `Products.class` in new class

```
public class Products {

    public String  id;
    public String  name;
    public String state;

    public Products() {
    }

    public Products(String name, String state) {
        this.name = name;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }


    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

}
```

I only add `id`(Necessary for position search), `name`, `state`
You can add other values to `Products.class`

**Third,** make the Firebase query to **get all products children**

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                        // for loop will be executed for each children
                        for(DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                            // put snapShot in Products.class ...... only children added
                            // in This case Children Will be price, quantity
                            Products products = userSnapshot.getValue(Products.class);

                            // set id manually to tha same instance of the class
                            products.setId(userSnapshot.getKey());

                            // add the Post class to ArrayList
                            productsArrayList.add(products);
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        //handle databaseError
                    }
                });
```

Now after products details are saved in `productsArrayList` you can use them anywhere.

**A helper method** to search in `ArrayList<Products>` and get specific `position`

```
 public int getArrayListProductsPosition(String id){

        for(int i = 0; i < productsArrayList.size() ; i++){

            // if the passed id equals some id in arrayList return arrayList position
            if(Objects.equals(productsArrayList.get(i).getId(), id)){
                return i;
            }

        }

        return 0;
    }
```

**Fourth,** Now anywhere the class if you need to access specific product details, to update `UI` for example;

```
    // pass the id of the product you want to get details about
    // I suppose this id will probably be retrived from another database tabel
    int position = getArrayListProductsPosition(id);

    //update your UI TextView quantity for example;
    String name = productsArrayList.get(position).getName()
    textQuantitiy.setText(name);

    // or update you UI ImageView for example;
```

**For more efficiency**

**--** in the search method (`getArrayListProductsPosition`), save products `id's` in database as numbers and change in `Products.class`. 
`String id` to `Long id` 
because `String-String` comparison is slower than `Long-Long` comparison

**--** if Products table is to be changed (not static) use the `productsArrayList` once and immediately after retrieve query (you don't want the data to be old)

Comment: OK I'll test it and I'll let you know ASAP,  by the way you know the limits of the firebase database? Size of db, queries to db, etc? I'm afraid now to use firebase

Comment: User stores name and mail, then product stores I'd product name product and state (free not free) and when user purchase an item I create a new table called purchased items where I store user I'd and all of products he has bought, what I'd like to do is make 1 simple query to populate the items (prods) and put the corresponding layout from user I mean if I did not bought anything it's the same as products table,  otherwise I'd like to change the item lockeds layout for those products that he/he has bought you got me?

Comment: yeah got you, do you show more than user in your app ? or only one and his related data ?

Comment: So far I was showing all the products that is what I want, but what I want is also to change the not free items (layout), to free layout if user has purchased for it and I can only know if user has purchased asking for purchased products and see if current user has the not free products to change the layout you got me now?

Comment: Well, you are handling this part well by addValueEventListener, and i think this means you show only one user data!!, that way you don't need to get all users from database, + you only get purchased products of that specific user from purchased table. though you can get the whole product table ONLY if products weren't many (very very big data )

Comment: I don't get you by the last comment you posted sorry :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162305/discussion-between-mohamed-embaby-and-skizo-oziks).

Comment: Embady hello again, you know if is there any problem if I add a different loggin to my app? I mean, I already have a google login, but I'd like to add antoher way will it be a problem with my db?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS you can add as logins as you want, facebook, google, twitter LinkedIn it's ok with ur db

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the code is optimized you could use shared-preference to save the purchased id for a user.Accessing the database might cause a delay in the program flow.using the data snapshot retrieve the product id and store it in a shared preference variable and check the product id while accessing the product details to show free layout.You could also keep items purchased information in the user id child to get more specified content search